# How to get member of Office 365 group in SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, user, office-365-groups

I have created user group **Group-1** in SharePoint Online Site. I have added few members in **Group-1**.

Now, I have created a group **Group-2** in Office 365 and added few members in the **Group-2**. Now I have added this **Group-2** in SharePoint Site.

Now when I am trying to get the Groups and Members of SharePoint Site then I am getting only Groups created in SharePoint, but I am not getting the group created in Office 365 and associated in SharePoint.

Note: I am able to see that **Group-2** in SharePoint using GUI but not members.

Question:

How can I get the **Group-2** and its Members in SharePoint programmatically?

Let me know if there is need of more details.

Answer (score 1):

you can get the user from that specific group using rest api as below.

```
http://sitename/_api/web/sitegroups/getbyname('Owners')/users
```

More at [enter link description here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/anavijai/how-to-get-all-the-users-from-site-group-in-sharepoint-2013/)

Comment: I really appreciate your answer, But the problem is, I am not able to get the Group-2 in all group list while I use this rest api call `https://SITEURL/_api/web/sitegroups`. Here I am getting only **Group-1** which is created in SharePoint Online.

Comment: How you added the Office 365 user group in sharepoint site? in any group or you grant the permission to that group?

Comment: I just simply clicked on Share link on the top of the site and added Group-2 there

Comment: Please check the answer below..

Answer (score 1):

Did you create an O365 group in Office 365 Admin Center directly?
If yes, you need to add members to the Group-2 in SharePoint site manually.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In That case it should added to any other group as a member. as in given screen shot I have shared site with "Test Group" which is office 365 group and it is added to Member Group of sharepoint site group.